# Razorpay Android SDK get transaction time

Tags: android, razorpay

I went through the Razorpay Android SDK Integration guide but was unable to find any reference for getting the transaction time for a successful payment transaction.

The integration guide shows the following way of listening to the payment result. Ref : [Step 5 - Handle Success and Error Events](https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/android-integration/standard/#step-5---handle-success-and-error-events)

```
public class MerchantActivity extends Activity implements PaymentResultListener {
  // ...

    @Override
  public void onPaymentSuccess(String razorpayPaymentID) {
        /**
     * Add your logic here for a successful payment response
     */
  }

  @Override
  public void onPaymentError(int code, String response) {
        /**
     * Add your logic here for a failed payment response
     */
  }
}
```

They have another alternative to this, which is PaymentResultWithDataListener with an object of PaymentData passed as an argument. It doesn`t have any data related to payment transaction time.

What is the alternative here? Using the device current timestamp can be one option but is not reliable because users tend to change the device date/time.

Comment: I have implemented Razor Pay and the date and time I have got is from our server end, so ask your backend guys to help you with that, they created an api in which I have to just pass the payment_id and they give all the details of the transaction including date and time.

Comment: Your Backend guys must be using the OrderId API provided by RazorPay. Irrespective of that, the transaction time they are providing you is the order creation timestamp. What I am interested in is the payment transaction time generated by Razorpay which should be returned by them. Paytm, Google Play, Google Pay and all other payment gateways do return transaction timestamp.

Comment: as you can see they only return payment_id, I will ask my back end guys how they have implemented it. But all I know this has to be done through back end and not from the app end for Razor Pay.

Comment: You can hit the Payments API from your backend to get the payment details. https://razorpay.com/docs/api/payments/#fetch-a-payment -This API needs a Payment ID, which you can get from the response in Android SDK.

Comment: Thanks @Vikas and @Umang. I guess the SDK doesn`t return the transaction timestamp then which I feel should be done by their app SDK though.

The exact transaction timestamp can be updated at the transaction verification step at backend after the app updates it about the payment.